# How can I get to the iterator of an array?

Tags: java

I'd like to use the following class like so:

```
for(String device : new Devices())
{
   //
}
```

If I provide direct access to the internal string array, then there is no problem:

```
for(String device : new Devices().getAllDevices()) //getAllDevices would be a String[]
{
   //
}
```

But I just want to forward the iterator, which would be simple if `AllDevices` were an `ArrayList`.

```
public final class Devices implements Iterable<String>{

    private static final String MyKindleFire = "123156448975312";

    private static final String[] AllDevices = new String[]{MyKindleFire};

    @Override
    public Iterator<String> iterator() {
        // if AllDevices were an array list, this would be possible
        // but how should I do this for an array?
        return AllDevices.iterator();
    }   
}
```

This works, but I'd like to know a better way if possible:

```
@Override
public Iterator<String> iterator() {
    return Arrays.asList(AllDevices).iterator();
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, you cannot do it without converting your array to `List<T>`: iterating over arrays with the "foreach" version of the `for` loop is a "compiler trick", i.e. something the compiler knows and does internally.

An ability to use primitives in "foreach" loops is an indirect indication that `Iterator<T>` is not used there, because Java generics cannot be used with primitive types.

Comment: That's a great point about the primitives, I didn't think about that.

Comment: A more direct "indication" [ :-) ] is the JLS 14.14.2 - http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.14.2 - which states exactly what the enhanced for loop means for arrays.

Answer (score 3):

```
String[] someArray = ....;
List<String> someList = java.util.Arrays.asList(someArray);
someList.iterator();
```

I think this is the only way to get an Iterator of an array in pure java.

If you are using apache commons-collections you can simply use:

```
org.apache.commons.collections.IteratorUtils.arrayIterator(Object[])
```

See http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/collections/IteratorUtils.html

Answer (score 2):

You could use Guava's [`Iterators.forArray(T...)`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Iterators.html#forArray%28T...%29) to make an iterator.

Alternatively, make an `Iterable` out of your array (e.g. with `Arrays.asList(T...)`) and return its `.iterator()`.

Comment: Yeah, I see a couple of libraries doing this, this one is interesting because it even comes with a comment that the `Arrays.asList` is preferable. "Note: It is often preferable to represent your data using a collection type, for example using `Arrays.asList(Object[])`, making this method unnecessary."